# LLVM: "Export" class

Tags: class, export, llvm

I'd like to call this code from my program using LLVM:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void hello() {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}

class Hello {
public:
  Hello() {
    std::cout <<"Hello::Hello()" << std::endl;
  };

  int hello() {
    std::cout<< "Hello::hello()" << std::endl;
    return 99;
  };
};
```

I compiled this code to llvm byte code using `clang++ -emit-llvm -c -o hello.bc hello.cpp` and then I want to call it from this program:

```
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/GenericValue.h>
#include <llvm/ExecutionEngine/JIT.h>
#include <llvm/LLVMContext.h>
#include <llvm/Module.h>
#include <llvm/Target/TargetSelect.h>
#include <llvm/Support/MemoryBuffer.h>
#include <llvm/Support/IRReader.h>

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace llvm;

void callFunction(string file, string function) {
  InitializeNativeTarget();
  LLVMContext context;
  string error;

  MemoryBuffer* buff = MemoryBuffer::getFile(file);
  assert(buff);
  Module* m = getLazyBitcodeModule(buff, context, &error);
  ExecutionEngine* engine = ExecutionEngine::create(m);    
  Function* func = m->getFunction(function);

  vector<GenericValue> args(0);    
  engine->runFunction(func, args);

  func = m->getFunction("Hello::Hello");
  engine->runFunction(func, args);
}

int main() {
  callFunction("hello.bc", "hello");
}
```

(compiled using `g++ -g main.cpp 'llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --libs core jit native bitreader'`)

I can call the `hello()` function without any problems.
My question is: how can I create a new instance of the `Hello` class using LLVM?
I'm getting a segmentation fault when I call `Hello::Hello()`

Thanks for any hints!!

Manuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `clang++ -emit-llvm` on the given source won't emit Hello::Hello, and `m->getFunction("Hello::Hello")` wouldn't find it even if it were emitted.  I would guess it's crashing because `func` is null.

Trying to directly call functions which aren't `extern "C"` from the LLVM JIT is generally not recommended... I'd suggest writing a wrapper like the following, and compiling it with clang (or using the clang API, depending on what you're doing):

```
extern "C" Hello* Hello_construct() {
  return new Hello;
}
```